# Custom error message based on SQL Exception code

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, exception, sqlexception

What would be the best way to catch the SQL exception code, and then use it to produce a custom error message?

I have a login page which fills out a custom connectionstring, then redirects to a page which uses said connection to access a database. On that page, it can throw errors depending on if I entered the correct login info, or if the database entered is wrong.

Can I just test the connection before I get to that page, or can I catch the exception code and bring it back to the login page?

Comment: I would personnally test the connection.

Comment: Yes, but _how_ do I test the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing was just "trying" to open the connection, and if it failed, catch the exception message, and put it on a label on the page.

```
    Dim queryString As String = "LOGINPROPERTY ( '" + Username + "' , 'property_name' )"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    Try
        connection.Open() 
        Response.Redirect("destination.aspx")
    Catch ex As Exception
        LabelError.Text = ex.Message
    Finally
    End Try
```

Answer (score 4):

This question is actually to wide. I will try to add an images to reduce lengthy code. I am considering only `UniqueConstraintException` in this example and will use C# instead of vb.net. Have to change my lot of code otherwise.

In my scenario, I created a `BaseException` class which is inherited from `Exception` class.

```
public class BaseException : Exception
{
    public BaseException()
        : base()
    { }

    public BaseException(string _exceptionMessage)
        : base(_exceptionMessage)
    {
    }

    public BaseException(string _exceptionMessage, Exception _innerException)
        : base(_exceptionMessage, _innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

Since I am interested SQL exceptions so I will create few more classes.

See my class diagram below, `SqlHelperException` is derived from BaseException class. SqlHelperException class object will be thrown by your `CRUD operations in DAL` hitting database,  should be handled by `BAL` layer.

```
public class SqlHelperException : BaseException
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public SqlHelperException()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public SqlHelperException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public SqlHelperException(string message, System.Exception innerException)
            : base(message, innerException)
        {
        }
    }
```

[image: Exception handling]

```
public class SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException : SqlHelperException
{
    public SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }

    public SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

Once my ground work is done, I wrote a `translator which accepts SqlException` and wraps it into SqlHelperException object

```
public static SqlHelperException TranslateException(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            SqlHelperException dalException = null;

            // Return the first Custom exception thrown by a RAISERROR
            foreach (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError error in ex.Errors)
            {
                if (error.Number >= 50000)
                {
                    dalException = new SqlHelperException(error.Message, ex);
                }
            }

            if (dalException == null)
            {
                // uses SQLServer 2005 ErrorCodes
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 2601:
                        // Unique Index/Constriant Violation
                        dalException = new SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException(ex.Message, ex);
                        //Overwrite Error message with your custom error message, we can use Resource file
                        dalException.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException;

                        break;
                    case 18456:
                        // Login Failed
                        dalException = new SqlHelperLoginException(ex.Message, ex);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // throw a general DAL Exception
                        dalException = new SqlHelperException(ex.Message, ex);
                        break;
                }
            }

            // return the error
            return dalException;
        }
```

Here in this translator, I used `ErrorMessages.SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException` static property which holds actual error message.

```
public class ErrorMessages
    {
     public static readonly string SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException;
     static ErrorMessages()
        {
            SqlHelperUniqueConstraintException = "{0} failed, duplicate {1}  already exists.";
        }
    }
```

Now in my DAL layer where I wrote my CRUD operations, I simply consumed these exceptions

```
public class Person
{
        public void Create()
        {
            SqlHelper sql = new SqlHelper();
            try
            {
                sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
            }
            catch (SqlEception ex)
            {
                var e =TranslateException(ex);
                e.ErrorMessage = string.Format(e.ErrorMessage, "Creation", "Person");
                throw e;
            }
        }
}
```

By doing so, at BAL I will get error message saying : **"Creation failed! duplicate person already exist."**